# Having an issue in Bootstrap with opacity of divs and buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a div with opacity and include a button. I cannot figure out why the button is getting the opacity as well as the div. But the text is fine. I want the button to have no opacity

CSS

```
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('../images/parkbanner.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  color: #000;
  padding: 150px 25px;
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
 }
 .container-fluid {
  padding: 60px 50px;
 }

.phone {
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 300px;
  height: 175px; 
 }
.phone p{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center"></div>    
    <div class="col-md-4 col-center">
    <div class="phone">
        <p>Please Don't Wait Until<br /> It's Too Late </p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span>  1-888-496-8059
            </button>
        </div>  
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[[image: Opacity Button Issue[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.phone` class remove `opacity` and add background with `rgba` then you're good

```
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
```

Comment: @GiBiT09 glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

Because button is included in class phone. Try removing it from that class or add opacity:0 property explicitly to button as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change the opacity of button.

```css
.phone buton{
  opacity: 1
}
```